# Draw area from given points on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I want to draw an area from given points on a map using the Google API on iPhone (I always have more than 2 points). If it is possible I want this area to be with alfa 0.5 (so people will be able to see routes underneath this area).

I would appreciate any code and links.

There are a few similar questions, but I didn't find anything just like this, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `MKOverlayView` and give it a proper `frame` (of type `CGRect`) calculated from the given points. Set the `alpha` of the view to 0.5. Note that `frame` and `alpha` are properties of `UIView`, of which `MKOverlayView` is a subclass.

Read everything about this class [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009715).

Comment: Could You give me some example?

Comment: Yes I did. I also check example, but I doesn't looks like I want. I want something like in Breadcrumb example. I will check both now:) Thanks